# Biblatex -- Caught signal: SEGV

Tags: biblatex

I get a fatal error compiling one of my documents -- "FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash:" -- and I'm not sure what's causing it.

All my googling indicates that there is a corrupt entry in my bib file, but I can't find it. Furthermore, my bib file is created by zotero and all my other documents use the same bib file and compile just fine.

I have tried cleaning out errors in the bib file by validating it and correcting errors (there were a few "date" fields with something other than a date), changing the relative path to my bib file to an absolute path, and duplicating my bib file to the same folder as the tex document (also correcting the path to \addbibresource{}).

from the doc preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{path/to/file.bib}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I get the same issue, have you managed to find the origin of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out there *was* a problematic bibtex entry. It's really strange that other documents continued to compile -- perhaps it's only relevant if you cite the particular reference with a problematic entry.

I ended up manually debugging the bib file in a manner that I found on another forum. Splitting the files in half and compiling until the problem entry is isolated. My bib file is a few thousand entries, so it took a while, but problem solved, at least.

Comment: Which forum do you talk about ? if you had a link ? regards